# How to modify the layout of jQuery UI autocomplete combobox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery UI autocomplete combobox and want to modify the layout of the combobox, for example the height/width of the text field/toggle button and font size/color of the input text, but I do not know how to specify the class in CSS.

For now, I'm only using `.ui-autocomplete-input` to change the height/width of the text field. Can anyone tell me how to modify other elements of the combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In their demo, http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html

they list the following styles within the head:

```
.custom-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.custom-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* support: IE7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
}
.custom-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
```

You can view all of the classes used by jquery ui here:
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css